# Populate Modal with data from SQL (query modified depending on clicked element)

Tags: php, sql, ajax, promise, bootstrap-modal

I have rows (not a table) that I populate with a php loop that retrieves the data from SQL.

Each row represents an EQUIPMENT.

When I generate the rows in php I assign to each row the equipment ID so I can after handle events based on the equipment ID.

One of the actions I want to perform is to display historical breakdowns associated with a given equipment ID.

I want to open a MODAL and display does historical breakdowns for the given Equipment ID.

I can display the breakdown through an ALERT, however I am not capable to populate the MODAL with the same text.

I believe that it might some misconception by my part on how I am using asynchronous calls.

"equipment.php" holds the equipment rows, those are created using this code

```
<button type="button" data-id="'.$row["equipment_id"].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#HistoricalModal">Historical</button>
```

"equipment.php" also holds the following functions (I STRONGLY believe that this is the problematic part)

```
$("#HistoricalModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    //get data-id attribute of the clicked element
    var equiID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    var body = setbody(equiID);
    //alert(body);
    //alert(JSON.stringify(body));
    body.then(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    var modal = $(this);
    changemodal(modal,body,equiID);    
});

function changemodal(modal,body,equiID) {
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Breakdown Records Equipment ' + equiID);
    modal.find('.modal-main-p').text('Equipment ' + body);
}

function setbody(equiID) {
    alert(equiID);
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/chaman/service/historical/historical_retrieve.php',
        data: 'equiID=' +equiID
    });
}
```

I've tried a lot of variations of the code above, like for example passing ...

```
changemodal(modal,body.then(function (data){return(data);}),equiID);
```

... as second argument to `changemodal()`, however nothing that I have seen in any of the examples seems to get this working.

`historical_retrieve.php` is the part of the code that makes the sql query (I believe this is fine).

```
<?php
require('../../chaman_db.php');
//Create connection 
    $equi_id = $_POST['equiID'];
    $my_connection=connect();
    $historical_raw=retrieveHistoricalRecords($my_connection,$equi_id);
    if ($historical_raw->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row       
    while($row = $historical_raw->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo'

    <div class="section-main"  id="'.$row["breakdown_id"].'">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-12">
            <p>
            Equipment: '.$row["breakdown_associated_equipment_id"].' '
            . 'Description: '.$row["breakdown_short_description"].' '
            . 'Date: '.$row["breakdown_date"].'
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';                

    }
    echo "";
    } else {
     echo "0 results";
    }
mysqli_close($my_connection);
```

equipment.php after the suggestions made by roamer (Works Fine) thank you. Edited: I also had  to change the function change modal to set the body as html instead of a text (it was displaying as raw the output from retrieve_historical.php)

```
    $("#HistoricalModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
    //get data-id attribute of the clicked element
    var equiID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    var body = setbody(equiID);
    var modal = $(this);
    body.then(function (data) {
        changemodal(modal,data,equiID);;
        });
    });

function changemodal(modal,body,equiID) {

    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Breakdown Records Equipment ' + equiID);
    modal.find('.modal-body').html(body);

}

function setbody(equiID){
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/chaman/service/historical/historical_retrieve.php',
        data: 'equiID=' +equiID
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. `setBody()` returns a jqXHR, which is a promise. You already use that promise correctly where you chain `then()` and call `alert()`. Move your `changemodal()` call into the `then()` callback and change the `body` argument to `data`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and for welcoming me. I tried your suggestion and it works perfectly. Now I just have to adjust the output from "historical_retreieve.php".

Comment: Pleased to help. When I get to a desktop machine, I will write a proper answer that you can accept. It would take half an age on this tablet and probably drive me nuts.